# Facebook Messenger bot is not sending message to the sender

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl, bots

I was following this [Tutorial](https://chatbotsmagazine.com/how-to-create-facebook-messenger-bot-in-php-2620784d5583#.okog2zogx) to create A Facebook Messenger bot using php

Everything is working fine, except sender don't receive my message.

there is my code

```
<?php
    $access_token =""; //Token
    $verify_token = ""; //Verify Token
    $hub_verify_token = null;
    if(isset($_REQUEST['hub_challenge'])) {
        $challenge = $_REQUEST['hub_challenge'];
        $hub_verify_token = $_REQUEST['hub_verify_token'];
    }
    if ($hub_verify_token === $verify_token) {
        echo $challenge;
    }
    $input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    $sender = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['sender']['id'];
    $message = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['text'];
    $message_to_reply = "Huh? You are talking to me?";
    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token='.$access_token;
    //Initiate cURL.
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    //The JSON data.
    $jsonData = '{
        "recipient":{
            "id":"'.$sender.'"
        },
        "message":{
            "text":"'.$message_to_reply.'"
        }
    }';
    //Encode the array into JSON.
    $jsonDataEncoded = $jsonData;
    //Tell cURL that we want to send a POST request.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    //Attach our encoded JSON string to the POST fields.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);
    //Set the content type to application/json
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
    //Execute the request
    if(!empty($input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message'])){
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        }
?>
```

I can receive the message and see it, But the user don't receive back my message.

Comment: You know that you have to submit your bot for review, before normal users that do not have a role in the app can use it, right? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/app-review

Comment: That isn't mentioned in the tutorial, So this is the problem? I just want to verify my code is working, it is not a production app.

Comment: Are you testing this with a user that has a role in the app?

Comment: Yes, I'm the creator of the app

Comment: Have you checked what response you got from the API for your message send request?

Comment: If you mean $result in `$result = curl_exec($ch);` it is empty (i have printed it in file using `fwrite($file, $result);` )

Comment: curl_exec only returns true or false by default; you need to set the option CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER for it to return the actual response body.

Comment: have an alternative facebook message implementation here https://github.com/divinity76/msgme - it uses the user interface, not the api, though, and the important parts is in https://github.com/divinity76/msgme/blob/master/src/php/relays/facebook.relay.php

Comment: @CBroe I made that but the result is still empty

Comment: @hanshenrik Looks like it's a completely different way, I just want to know why API is not working with me and know what is the problem exactly.

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed by adding following lines of code before //Execute the request

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $jsonData = '{
    "messaging_type": "RESPONSE",
    "recipient":{
        "id": "' . $sender . '"
    }, 
    "message":{
        "text": "teste web"
    }
}';
$s="";
//Tell cURL that we want to send a POST request.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
//Attach our encoded JSON string to the POST fields.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);
//Set the content type to application/json
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$ret = curl_exec($ch);
```